# Erro ao obter token em interceptor - Type 'Promise<void | Observable<HttpEvent<any>>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Estou criando um interceptor para enviar o token juntamente com as requisições para a Api.

Eu uso `@ionic/storage` para guardar as informações do meu usuário. Porém, quando eu tento obter o token no construtor para guardar em uma variável (ex: private token: string), o meu interceptor não consegue obter esse valor mesmo o token existindo. **Creio que isso acontece pq o intercept é executado antes da função this.storage.get finalizar.**

Como posso corrigir isso?

Já tentei colocar a função `this.storage.get` dentro do intercept, porém da erro de retorno:

**"Type 'Promise>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable>'.  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Promise>>'."**

Vejam o código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço a ajuda.﻿

Answer (score 0):

A resposta veio de um usuário do stackoverflow.com

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
var promise = this.storage.get('token')
    .then((token) => {
        if (token) {
            const newRequest = req.clone({ setHeaders: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` } });

            return next.handle(newRequest);
        } else {
            return next.handle(req);
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        //TODO: Trata erro
        throw error;
    })
return Observable.fromPromise(promise);
```

}